# String manipulation pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, format

I have a column named `Timestamp` of type `str`, and I would like to change the values of the column to a more appropriate format, i.e. `353` to `3:53 pm`.

How can I do this using pandas or appropriate string manipulation?

```py
c = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp":x,"Latitude":y,"Longitude":z})
c.head()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%H%M').dt.time`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also work:

```py
from datetime import datetime

c['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.rjust(4, '0'), '%H%M').strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Comment: is there any pro or contra to use 1st or 2nd solution? I just checked it, and both times the col is the same and cells are strings....so I guess, it doesn't matter ?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If your data is just %H%M, and you want a colon, they're basically equivalent. If you have data in a more complex date format, I'd use this `datetime` solution because it's much easier to manipulate full dates using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `apply` on the column and pass a function that will split each string and insert a colon:

```py
c['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x[0:-2] + ':' + x[-2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

(just wanted to get this in here)

As @ChrisA mentioned in the comments, you can also do this:

```py
c['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(c['Timestamp'], format='%H%M').dt.time
```